# Python threading stopping code from being executed

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I have this code here:

```
from threading import Thread
import time

class TestClass():

    def __init__ (self, name):
        self.name = name

        self.thread = Thread(target=self.run())
        
        self.thread.start()

    def run(self):
        while True:
            print(self.name)

            time.sleep(1)

test = TestClass('word')

print('done')
```

So basically this just keeps printing 'word', without it ever printing 'done' . This is a small demonstration of the problem I'm having, cause threading is getting stuck and it's stopping other lines of code from being executed. You can try this on your own and you will get same results. Is anything I'm missing here?

Comment: This will keep printing word because you have put an infinite loop. The execution will not stop so it is not printing done.

Comment: Yeah but, it is ran on a thread. Isn't that the purpose of threading? So you can do other stuff without stopping the loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should work and is the recommended way to use the Thread class.

```
from threading import Thread
import time

class TestClass(Thread):

    def __init__ (self, name):
        super().__init__()
        self.name = name
        self.start()

    def run(self):
        while True:
            print(self.name)

            time.sleep(1)

test = TestClass('word')

print('done')
```